# How to get Before Edit and After Edit of a Textbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I am using PRISM MVVM to show a Listview of files containing an image, a filename and the size of the image.

The user should be able to change the name of the file by typing in a new name.
When leaving the text box the filename in my ViewModel should be renamed. For this i need of course to know the Text as it was before and after.

I don't want to use Code behind, but I guess I need to work with GotFocus to store the value before and on LostFocus to get the new value. Right?

This is my XAML

```
  <Grid>   
    <ListView x:Name="MiscFilesListView" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding MiscFiles}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <UniformGrid Columns="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Image Source="{Binding ImageData}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="100" Width="100" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding FileName}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Size}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
          </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
  </Grid>
```

The Listview is bound to:

```
public ObservableCollection<MiscFile> MiscFiles
{
   get => _miscFiles;
   set => SetProperty(ref _miscFiles, value);
}
```

The viewmodel

```
  public class MiscFile : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    public BitmapImage ImageData { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FullFileName { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyname)
    {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  }
```

Any idea how I can achieve this inside the Viewmodel?
Do I need some sort of EventTrigger?

Comment: Have you considered using IEditableObject as a basis for your model class, and then on save, you have the before / after of the data?

Comment: Since it seems to only be the one property, you could have an original value property you set when you new that up l.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a private field for the filename in the viewmodel. The public FileName property should check if the value is different from the value set in the private field. Also notify the INotifyPropertyChanged by calling `OnPropertyChanged`.
Doing this should update the filename property.

If you want to keep the old filename it is possible to call the `Path.GetFileName(FullFileName)` method of the static Path class.

```
private string _filename;
public BitmapImage ImageData
{
    get;set;
}

public string FileName
{
    get
    {
        return _filename;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_filename != value)
        {
            _filename = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FileName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked fine. Didn't think about the obvious one.

Answer (score 0):

The previous value is already stored in your `MiscFile` object. Just define a backing field for your property:

```
private string _filename;
public string FileName
{
    get { return _filename; }
    set
    {
        string oldValue = _filename;
        string newValue = value;

        //update...
        _filename = value;
    }
}
```

This should work as the source property shouldn't be set until the `TextBox` loses focus since you haven't changed the `UpdateSourceTrigger` property of the binding from its default value of `LostFocus`:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding FileName, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" ... />
```

Comment: Thanks, worked fine. I marked the previous post as answer, since his posting was earlier.